# AWS Cloudfront Signed Cookie not working on alternate domain

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

## Problem

I have `Access Denied` for GET request to cloudfront with signed cookies using both canned and custom policy.

## Details

1. `cdn.example.com` is the alternate domain of `abc.cloudfront.net`, and CNAME is set on both cloudfront and cloudflare.
2. I expect after `abc.example.com/authorize`, `cdn.example.com` is accessible.
3. I am using PHP with Laravel behind `abc.example.com/authroize`, and the code is as follows.

```

```
$cloudFront = new Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient([
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => '2014-11-06'
]);

$resourceKey = 'http://cdn.example.com';
$expires = time() + 300;

$signedCookieCannedPolicy = $cloudFront->getSignedCookie([
        'url'         => $resourceKey,
        'expires'     => $expires,
        'private_key' => 'pk.pem',
        'key_pair_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
]);

$response = Response::success();
foreach ($signedCookieCannedPolicy as $name => $value) {
    $response->withCookie(Cookie::make($name, $value, 360, null, 'example.com'));
}

return $response;
```

```

4. The cookies are set for `.example.com`

[image]

5. When I go to `cdn.example.com`, the following message is shown

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having the same issue

Comment: If I don't remember wrong, the issue was due to the encrypted cookies. You might want to check:
https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.html#method_make
And if you are using Laravel 5.2, make sure you added exception if you used middleware to encrypt.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was due to the encrypted cookies. You might want to check: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.html#method_make And if you are using Laravel 5.2, make sure you added exception if you used middleware to encrypt.